# Is [ip] really necessary?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I direct your attention to the [ip](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip) tag.

Is it really necessary? Who is going to subscribe to a tag like that? It just doesn't seem to be a useful tag at all.

And, to be pedantic, if it's going to remain it should be [ip-addresses](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip-addresses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Point taken. I should have rejected the suggested edits.

I have reworked the tag wiki and renamed the tag from [ip](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip) to [ip-addresses](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip-addresses)